# Select records by their closest point and order by ascending distance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table of `listings` of which each has multiple `listing_coordinates` records. Given a specific point (for example `ST_Point ('-118.1885', '33.7775')`) I want to retrieve all `listings` that have a coordinate within 25 kilometres of that point and order them by their closest point. In addition I'd like access to that `distance` in the result too.

`listing_coordinates.coordinate` is of type `geography(Point, 4326)` and has a spatial index of `(coordinate)::geography` on it.

```sql
SELECT
  "listings".*,
  (
    SELECT
      ST_Distance(coordinate, ST_Point ('-118.1885', '33.7775')) AS distance
    FROM
      "listing_coordinates"
    WHERE
      "listing_coordinates"."listing_id" = "listings"."id"
    ORDER BY
      "distance" ASC
    LIMIT 1) AS "distance"
FROM
  "listings"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      "listing_coordinates"
    WHERE
      "listings"."id" = "listing_coordinates"."listing_id"
      AND ST_DWithin (ST_Point ('-118.1885', '33.7775'), listing_coordinates.coordinate, 25000, FALSE))
  ORDER BY
    "distance" ASC
  LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0
```

The performance of this query isn't great - even locally it's hovering around 3-400ms. Removing the `WHERE EXISTS` clause doesn't appear to have an impact either.

I suspect I'm approaching this problem incorrectly, rather than missing or not using an index correctly.

What would be the best way to query `listings` that have a `coordinate` with a certain radius and order it by their closest point ascending?

Comment: I think this can be rewritten to something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/245431/6253

Comment: You could try a `LATERAL JOIN` like in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/297244/78402